# How to find an xpath present in the current page?

Tags: xpath

I have the Xpath "//td[contains(@class,'list-padding radar_text')]/a[contains(@href,'id')]"))".

In my web page, once after submitting a form,page will be reloaded with some dynamically created details. the given XPath is for  one of the  field. before fetching the value of this XPath i want to check whether this Xpath exist in that page.

Comment: Well you will need to explain which XPath API you use. Do you want to use XPath with Javascript in a HTML document loaded in a browser? Mozilla, Safari, Opera, Chrome expose an API for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript.

Comment: You could wrap the given XPath in boolean() and test for true.